# rosrun of a working python script fails

Tags: ros, python, package, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have written a python code using different libraries I already installed (pygame, pyaudio etc...).
My script is working very well when I run it using

```
python myscript.py
```

but when I put it in my ros package and after making it executable and running it using

```
rosrun mypackage myscript
```

it shows some error messages when I click with the mouse and then crashes.
Here is the error I get:

```
    import: unable to grab mouse `': Resource temporarily unavailable @ error/xwindow.c/XSelectWindow/9052.
import: unable to grab mouse `': Resource temporarily unavailable @ error/xwindow.c/XSelectWindow/9052.
import: unable to grab mouse `': Resource temporarily unavailable @ error/xwindow.c/XSelectWindow/9052.
import: unable to grab mouse `': Resource temporarily unavailable @ error/xwindow.c/XSelectWindow/9052.
import: unable to grab mouse `': Resource temporarily unavailable @ error/xwindow.c/XSelectWindow/9052.
import: unable to grab mouse `': Resource temporarily unavailable @ error/xwindow.c/XSelectWindow/9052.
import: unable to grab mouse `': Resource temporarily unavailable @ error/xwindow.c/XSelectWindow/9052.
from: can't read /var/mail/std_msgs.msg
import: unable to grab mouse `': Resource temporarily unavailable @ error/xwindow.c/XSelectWindow/9052.
import: unable to grab mouse `': Resource temporarily unavailable @ error/xwindow.c/XSelectWindow/9052.
/home/tlili/groovy_workspace/sandbox/BILHR_ros/src/ASR_node.py: line 16: LANG_CODE: command not found
/home/tlili/groovy_workspace/sandbox/BILHR_ros/src/ASR_node.py: line 17: KEY_TLILI: command not found
/home/tlili/groovy_workspace/sandbox/BILHR_ros/src/ASR_node.py: line 18: OTHER_KEY: command not found
/home/tlili/groovy_workspace/sandbox/BILHR_ros/src/ASR_node.py: line 20: GOOGLE_SPEECH_URL: command not found
/home/tlili/groovy_workspace/sandbox/BILHR_ros/src/ASR_node.py: line 21: FLAC_CONV: command not found
/home/tlili/groovy_workspace/sandbox/BILHR_ros/src/ASR_node.py: line 22: INITIAL_SPEECH_THRESHOLD: command not found
/home/tlili/groovy_workspace/sandbox/BILHR_ros/src/ASR_node.py: line 23: FORMAT: command not found
/home/tlili/groovy_workspace/sandbox/BILHR_ros/src/ASR_node.py: line 24: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/home/tlili/groovy_workspace/sandbox/BILHR_ros/src/ASR_node.py: line 24: `SHORT_NORMALIZE = (1.0/32768.0)'
```

And this is the main part of my script, it basically start saving audio from a microphone when the mouse is clicking on a small black window and when the mouse is released the audio is sent to google speech to text API.

```
    pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()                                 #]
stream = pa.open(format = FORMAT,                      #|
         channels = CHANNELS,                          #|---- You always use this in pyaudio...
         rate = RATE,                                  #|
         input = True,                                 #|
         frames_per_buffer = INPUT_FRAMES_PER_BLOCK)   #]

speech_threshold = INITIAL_SPEECH_THRESHOLD            #]
noisycount = 0                                         #|---- Variables for noise detector...
quietcount = 0                                         #|
errorcount = 0                                                      #]         
frames = []
isSaving = 0
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((300,200))
pygame.display.set_caption('Testing')
running = True
#Ros objects to publish strings received after ASR
pub = rospy.Publisher('speech',String)
rospy.init_node('ASR',anonymous=True)
while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    
    try:                                                    #]
        block = stream.read(INPUT_FRAMES_PER_BLOCK)         #|
    except IOError, e:                                      #|---- just in case there is an error!
        errorcount += 1                                     #|
        print( "(%d) Error recording: %s"%(errorcount,e) )  #|
                                                              #]
    pressed = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]
    if isSaving:
        frames.append(block)
        noisycount += 1
        quietcount = 0
        print(len(frames))
    ev = pygame.event.get()
    for event in ev:
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            isSaving = 1
            print 'started recording'
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP: # if its to loud...
            if isSaving:
                isSaving = 0
                print 'speech detected!'
                save_audio(frames,pa)
                r =  (stt_google_wav(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME))
                print(r)
                if(len(r)):
                    pub.publish(r)
            frames = []
            quietcount += 1
            noisycount = 0
    pygame.event.pump()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/164091/rosrun-of-a-working-python-script-fails/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2014-05-12

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the script is being executed by the shell, not python. Does your script start with a shebang line? Such as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-05-13**:
Thanks, that solved my problem :D